# How can I get Aperture to use gmail for emailing photos?

Tags: macos, gmail, aperture

I use gmail in a web browser.  I don't use Mail at all.

Except...

In Aperture if I go share -> email it opens up Mail.app.

Is there a way through configuration or through a helper app to get aperture to open share by email pix in a gmail composer window?

I'm using Aperture 3.6 on Yosemite.

---

Edit:  Currently Mail is set to have Default Mail Reader is Google Chrome.  This works for (so far) everything but Aperture.

Comment: tell me if my answer is what you're looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

To make "share by email" buttons on your Mac (system-wide!) open up in Gmail—instead of the Mail app—follow these instructions:

-Download and install Google Chrome, if it's not on your Mac already.

-Open the Mail app--yes, the stock Mail app.

-Press "Mail" on the menu-bar, in the top-left of your screen, and hit Preferences.

-Make sure you're in the General pane, and press "Choose default Email Reader".

-Choose Google Chrome from the dropdown menu.

Now your system-wide default email viewer is Gmail in the web. Let me know if this helped you!

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/06/change-default-mail-app-mac/